# Proving calculus equations by geometry means

Tags: calculus, geometry, systems-of-equations

The following drawing depicts the solution of a second order equation by 2D geometrical means.

[image]

Following this work I developed the equation for the 3D case of a Cuboid.

$
1. \:uvw= V \quad (V - Box/cuboid volume)\\
2. \:uv+uw+vw = \frac{S}{2} \quad (S – Cuboid surface)\\
3. \:u+v+w = \frac{L}{4} \quad (L – sum of Cuboid edges)\\
4. \:vw = \frac{V}{u}\\
5. \:v+w = \frac{L}{4} \, – \, u\\
\:\: \:Insert\:  4\: and\: 5\: into\: 2\: to\: get\: equation\: for\: u \\
6. \:u^3-\frac{L}{4}u^2+\frac{S}{2}u-V=0
$

Every equation similar to the above that has 3 real positive solutions may be expressed as Cuboid with the edges equal to the solution.

$
7. \:(u-r_1)X(u-r_2)X(u-r_3)=u^3-(r_1+r_2+r_3)u^2+(r_1 r_2+r_1 r_3+r_2 r_3)u+r_1 r_2 r_3
$

Which may be mapped to 6 with 1 to 1 relation.
My challenge/effort is to demonstrate geometrically a solution for 6 - in 2D (preferred) or 3D.
Any suggestions?

An example of a potential step will be figuring the relation between the length of the edges to the surface of the sides, as depicted in the following drawing:
[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubling_the_cube

Comment: @Inteligenti pauca I understand that your message that this is impossible. The advantage here that it is different than solving $x^3 - 2 = 0$ which the decomposition includes the troubling $\sqrt[3]{2}$. Here, since the three roots are real and positive, the situation is different and may allow for a solution.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca is correct. And I don't know why you refuse to respond to the clear answer I gave.

Comment: You cannot solve the specific cube problems - I emphasized that there are some cases you could solve - not for all cases. There clearly cases that will not have a solution. Given a 1X1X1 box - can you find a 2X1X1 box? This box is double the volume of the original and could be described as a solution to a polynomial.

Comment: You last comment makes no sense. Your equation (6) is clearly generic. Just like you say you can geometrically solve the quadratic equation $u^2-Lu+S = 0$ for arbitrary $L,S$ such that it has real solutions, you want to do the same for the cubic. You have not admitted that my answer showed that your reply to @Intelligentipauca was irrelevant (because it's easy to manipulate the cubic I gave to get one with positive real roots that **are not constructible**). **No** compass and straightedge construction can solve (6) in any general sense, and this is just basic field theory.

Comment: Do you see the difference between claiming that ALL equation systems are not solvable and that there are some cases in which you could apply a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you understand **why** doubling the cube is impossible with straightedge and compass, you would also understand that your goal is similarly not constructible (by straightedge and compass). Having three real roots does not help in constructing the roots at all; $t^3-6t+3$ is irreducible in $ℚ[t]$ and has three real roots.